# JOOQ "IN" Query throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, sql, jooq

When we try to fetch data with Null values

`field(TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME.in(null))`

with IN clause
getting null pointer exception.

Maybe because of this.

```
  @Override
    public final Condition in(Collection<?> values) {
        Field<?>[] fields = new Field[values.size()];

        Iterator<?> it = values.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; it.hasNext(); i++)
            fields[i] = Tools.field(it.next(), this);

        return in(fields);
    }
```

In the database, we can provide null in IN clause.

There is an existing "won't fix" issue in jooq https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3867

There are some alternatives:

- check null before IN(Cant do in my case its a really big select statement)

So if I want to make this possible is there any other workaround.

PS: On a similar note "eq" works perfectly fine:

```
@Override
    public final Condition equal(Field<T> field) {
        return compare(EQUALS, nullSafe(field, getDataType()));
    }
```

Edit: 'field(TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME.in(null))' here null is a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code doesn't compile:

```java
TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME.in(null)
```

There are 5 overloads of this `in()` method in jOOQ 3.14, and as such, you cannot pass the `null` literal to the `in()` method. Your real client code may be using a local variable like this:

```java
Collection<?> collection = null;
TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME.in(collection)
```

There might be a case for when this should behave the same as passing an empty collection, such as `Collections.emptyList()`, but this isn't what you seem to want. You probably want to pass actual `null` values *inside* of that collection, which you can do:

```java
TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME.in(1, null, 2)
```

But why would you do it? SQL implements [three valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), meaning that `NULL` values have no effect in `IN` predicates, while they have an unintuitive, hardly desired effect in `NOT IN` predicates (the entire predicate becomes `NULL`)

Comment: @Lucas In our query that a condition where in query we might get Null. And yes we are checking with the collection and that collection can be null so we end up using this 


===========
isNull(collection)
                ? field(DSL.sql("null")).as(Column_Dummy_Name)
                : field(TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME.in(collection)).as(Column_Dummy_Name)
=========

Let me know if you have any other thoughts.

Comment: @GuaravRatnawat: But see, if jOOQ allowed for `null` collections to be passed to `in()` then it would behave the same as an empty collection, which isn't the same thing as replacing it by `field("null")`, it would be the same as `inline(false)`, so not what you wanted. It's a good idea to be explicit about your intent on your side.